# How to parse the X Y of a Point via List index value?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, parsing, point

I apologise if my question is confusing, it is very early in the morning here.
To summarise, I am trying to retrieve then set the x and y of a Point into ShipPosX and ShipPosY, which are int values in the Ship class/object. I am accessing the Point as an element of a List and cannot quite grasp how to accomplish this. This is in C# Winform.

```
  //foreach Ship in fleet, pick Point from spawnPos and display ship images
        foreach (Ship item in fleet)
        {
            int p = new Random().Next(0, spawnPos.Count);

            using (Graphics gr = this.CreateGraphics())
            {
                Image newImage = Image.FromFile(item.imgShip); //create image
                gr.DrawImage(newImage, spawnPos.ElementAt(p)); //draw
                imgPos.Add(newImage); //add to image list
                item.ShipPosX = int.Parse(spawnPos.ElementAt(p).ToString()); //make point xy strings and then int
                item.ShipPosY = int.Parse(spawnPos.ElementAt(p).ToString());
            }

            spawnPos.RemoveAt(p); //remove used Point to avoid duplicate
        }
```

As you can probably tell I'm lost trying to convert at;

```
item.ShipPosX = int.Parse(spawnPos.ElementAt(p).ToString());
item.ShipPosY = int.Parse(spawnPos.ElementAt(p).ToString());
```

If anyone could advise on how to properly find what I'm looking for I would appreciate it greatly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well I feel foolish, all I needed to change was;

```
item.ShipPosX = int.Parse(spawnPos.ElementAt(p).X.ToString());
item.ShipPosY = int.Parse(spawnPos.ElementAt(p).Y.ToString());
```

As ever it's the small details that elude you at 7am.